# How do I provide incentive to answer my question when I have no reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, unanswered-questions

My user page on Stack Overflow is asking me if I have "considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty" for the following question:

[Windows Mobile App - Play MMS Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106947/windows-mobile-app-play-mms-stream)

Which happens to be my first participation on this site.  I've gathered the basics of how this all works, and I even understand the concept of a bounty (which is brilliant by the way).

However, there is nowhere in the UI where I am offered the ability to provide a bounty because I am started off with so little reputation (1 to be exact).  My question is most definitely not answered either.

I'm really at a loss for how to give my question more visibility (and more incentive) while being so restricted as a new user to the site?  Is this the way it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are also working on a solution to your question, via other research or even just trial and error.  Edit your question to show the results of that research and it will be 'bumped' back to the top of the home page and the active view so that others can see it and know about any new information you might discover.

Other than that, there's already a 'bounty' of 15 reputation for any non-community wiki question.

Comment: So...I accidentally clicked the "community wiki" checkbox.  I tried emailing the StackOverflow team, but was given a response that they thought it was pretty clear what the checkbox was for, despite my assertion that it was a little confusing and less intuitive.  I noted that I couldn't undo the "community wiki" conversion and asked if it could be reversed.  The answer I got was a confirmation that I couldn't reverse it myself.

But I have done just as you said as far as bumping it back to the top and updating with my own research.

Not much more I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can, failing everything else, (although there is a discussion about having a grace period to unwikify questions) ask the question again (now without the CW clicked) stating what's the current situation.

Comment: I'm actually trying this solution, as my situation with the "Community Wiki" is unique.  As soon as I get enough rep i will vote your answer up.  I encourage others to vote this one up too, in addition to the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Contribute to the site by answering other people's questions, so that you can build the necessary reputation perhaps?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question.  But nonetheless, I realize that is the point of the site.

Comment: It does answer part of your question. You asked: "I'm really at a loss for how to give my question more visibility (and more incentive) while being so restricted as a new user to the site? Is this the way it should be?" If you answer more questions, you get rep points and badges, which are displayed next to questions you ask. These show other members you're a serious user and people will be more likely to answer your question. Also, you can use the rep you earn to start a bounty.