# How can I "wake a question up"?

Tags: support, bounties, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I posted a question like a week ago, and received no answers.

How can I "wake-up" the question? In other words, how can I make people notice it again?

I could offer a bounty, but it'd only be good for a week, and then I'd lose my points... I've tried that, but I'm afraid it might not help.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/how-do-i-provide-incentive-to-answer-my-question-when-i-have-no-reputation or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75361/what-to-do-when-your-question-is-still-unanswered-but-on-page-11

Answer (score 0):

You could look at ways to improve your question and edit accordingly - this will bring it back on the active page. Or leave it for the [Community user to poke your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

Be careful about editing your posts as editing it more than 10 times will make the post [Community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)